# Compilation error when trying to initialize vector of structs

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to initialize vector of structs and I'm getting compilation error.

As far as my understanding goes initializing vector of structs is easy when struct contains straightforward data types like int, float, etc. but what if i have several char arrays inside?

```cpp
#include <vector>

/// this compiles without any problem:
typedef struct TEST_TYPE_A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

std :: vector <TEST_TYPE_A> TEST_A =
{
    {1,2,1,2},
    {4,5,6,4},
    {7,8,8,9},
    {0,1,10,11},
    {3,4,99,200}
};/// so far good, no compilation error


/// this variant fails
typedef struct TEST_TYPE_B
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char txt1[10];
    char txt2[3];
};

std :: vector <TEST_TYPE_B> TEST_B =
{
    {1,2,"1010101111","ABC"},
    {4,5,"1010101111","ABC"},
    {7,8,"1010101111","ABC"},
    {0,1,"1010101111","ABC"},
    {3,4,"1010101111","ABC"}
}; /// i get compilation error here
```

Compilation error:

```
error: could not convert '{{1, 2, "1010101111", "ABC"}, {4, 5, "1010101111", "ABC"}, {7, 8, "1010101111", "ABC"}, {0, 1, "1010101111", "ABC"}, {3, 4, "1010101111", "ABC"}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<TEST_TYPE_B>'
```

I've seen similar problem here with `string` type instead of `char[NUM]` array which appeared to be working. I understand that since I'm initializing array it will need some special treatment but I don't know how to do it as simple as possible. I'm not going to pretend I'm educated enough and simply ask whats wrong and how can i fix it? 
I'm using GCC 5.1 and C++11.

Comment: `"ABC"` is a `const char[4]` (there is final `\0`), so, incompatible with `char txt2[3]`.

Comment: Your `typedef`s are superfluous

Comment: why arent you using `std::string`? btw dont  write `std :: vector`, among other things it kills any search function when you want to find `std::vector`

Comment: @jarod42 Thanks, that was a typo. I tried to create simple example of the problem. but still problem persists.

Comment: identifiers with `ALL_CAPITAL_LETTERS` like `TEST_TYPE_A` are idiomatically used for macros.

Comment: `{1,2,"1010101111","ABC"}` would have to be in many cases (with other type of array than `char[]`) `{1,2,{'1', '0', '1', ...},{'A', 'B', "C', 0}},...`, i.e. you are also missing inner curly braces, but with `char[]` and C-string like `"ABC"` I guess all common compilers will get it and compile it as expected (but you need to account for the zero byte terminator, i.e. resize arrays to 11 and 4). With the per-char init like `{'A','B','C'}` you can actually achieve 3-byte array with `ABC` content (but you can't use it as C-string like for `printf`, as that requires zero-terminated string data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::string` instead of c-style null-terminated arrays. `std::string` is less error-prone and there is usually no reason to avoid it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct TEST_TYPE_B
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::string txt1;
    std::string txt2;
};

std::vector <TEST_TYPE_B> TEST_B =
{
    {1, 2, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    {4, 5, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    {7, 8, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    {0, 1, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    {3, 4, "1010101111", "ABC"}
};
```

[Compiles fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VQ1NO8)

If you want to keep using `char[]`, and arrays are large enough to hold the text, compilers seem to disagree on if the code is valid (clang compiles it, gcc doesn't). But they all agree with this form:

```
std::vector <TEST_TYPE_B> TEST_B =
{
    TEST_TYPE_B{1, 2, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    TEST_TYPE_B{4, 5, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    TEST_TYPE_B{7, 8, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    TEST_TYPE_B{0, 1, "1010101111", "ABC"},
    TEST_TYPE_B{3, 4, "1010101111", "ABC"}
};
```

Comment: Fixed size array has its utility too, if `txt1` has to have exactly (or up to) 10 chars , `char[10]` or `std::array<char, 10>` better fits than std::string.

Comment: @Ayxan This solution while working is not usable because right now for me. Program I'm developing started as pure C and went through roller coaster of changing requirements. Right now it is C++ but with parts written in C. In this stage of development i cannot afford modifying it to pure C++ and believe me it would solve lot of problems. I just have to finish it somehow.

Comment: @Jarod42 exactly why `std::array<char, 10>` is a better fit? It is harder to print,  it is less common to use `std::array` to represent text, and this example [won't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EZscsH) with `std::array`

Comment: if nul-terminated, `text.data()`, else there is still `std::string_view(begin(text), end(text))` so printing is not a issue. Initialization is indeed harder, but, some compilers warn if we use more than 10 char when initializing the array whereas `std::string` happily accepts string longer than **expected**. OP's type might represent a format with fixed size string for example. I didn't say that in general case std::string is not better, I say that in specific case, it is not necessary the best one. In the same way `std::array` has usage over `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Your txt1 and txt2 members of TEST_TYPE_B are actually arrays. So to initialize them the way you are doing it now you would have to change it to this (just did it for the first TEST_TYPE_B) :

```
std :: vector <TEST_TYPE_B> TEST_B =
{
    {1,2,{'1','0','1','0','1','0','1','1','1','1'},{'A','B','C'}}
};
```

However, there are better ways than doing this that got already covered in other answers. I mainly added this answer to explain what's exactly wrong with your code. You probably should change your txt1 and txt2 to std::string like in the answer provided by Ayxan.